# How can I use PBFT in fabric 2.0 for a multi organization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Hi im new to blockchain fabric. I went through all the documentation can anyone tell me how I can implement PBFT algo in hyperledger fabric 2.0 ...

Answer (score 1):

There is no PBFT in Fabric 2.0 or in the official Fabric 1.4, but there is going to be some BFT consensus available in the future.

There are **unofficial** BFT consensus implementations of Fabric, like [this one](https://github.com/SmartBFT-Go) which is based on the 1.4 branch, and in the future will also be ported to the 2.0 branch.

If you want to try it out, there are [docker images](https://hub.docker.com/u/smartbft) available, as well as a [sample](https://github.com/SmartBFT-Go/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4-BFT/first-network/byfn.sh#L439).